# jQuery: play background video according to variable defining the source

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, video

I try to embed a jQuery task to play a video (saved locally) based on a weather-IP.

e.g. `var selectedVideo = video[weatherIP];`

This code works fine and respective video gets selected:

```
console.log(selectedVideo);
sunshine.mp4
```

The following jQuery code also works:

```
$("#myVideo").html('<source src="sunshine.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source>');
```

But by exchanging the string

> sunshine.mp4

with the

> var = selectedVideo

```
$("#myVideo").html('<source src=\"" + selectedVideo + "\" type="video/mp4"> </source>');
```

I get an error sayin that not all candidates for this resource can get loaded - loading media paused...

hence no video gets loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please keep it in English one this site

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/ is just about german as language, it's not computer related.

Comment: `$("#myVideo").html('<source src="'' + selectedVideo + '" type="video/mp4"> </source>');` ?

Comment: As Manuel points out: this is merely a typo (as presented), you’ve mixed up your string delimiters.

Comment: alright figured it out differently with

$("#myVideo").attr("src",selectedVideo);

Thanks guys!